# What is the correct way to give inputs, which contains data with different shapes, to the NN?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

My inputs to the NN include several matrix/vectors/scalars representing different physical measurements.

Currently I just reshape the matrix to vectors, and then combine everything to an 1 x N vector. I don't know if it's the correct or best way deal with them. Intuitively I feel that maybe it's an better way to give them to individual input layers and them sum them in a later layer.

My question is : What is the correct way to give inputs, which contains data with different shapes, to the NN?

Comment: It depends on what the shape of the data means. Does it represent time, or space? What kind of neural network is it? If you have a specific question about applying neural networks to a domain, I recommend asking on another site, perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning+neural-networks

Comment: @Gus Basically the shapes of matrix represent space. I'm using reinforcement learning for a control problem now, but I also have such question for mlp or cnn. I'll also try to consult on other sites. Thank you!